# What is reason to call reauthorizeRequest in spring oauth2 client

Tags: spring-security, spring-oauth2

I was just going through the code of `ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction` from `spring-security-oauth2-client-6.0.5.jar`. I copied below snippet from `ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction`. Here first it calls `authorizeRequest` and the calls `reauthorizeRequest`. Why request has to be reauthorized. I feel in first method `authorizeRequest` the flow should have got the access token that needs to passed.

```
private Mono<OAuth2AuthorizedClient> authorizedClient(ClientRequest request) {
    OAuth2AuthorizedClient authorizedClientFromAttrs = oauth2AuthorizedClient(request);
    // @formatter:off
    return Mono.justOrEmpty(authorizedClientFromAttrs)
            .switchIfEmpty(Mono.defer(() -> authorizeRequest(request)
                    .flatMap(this.authorizedClientManager::authorize))
            )
            .flatMap((authorizedClient) -> reauthorizeRequest(request, authorizedClient)
                    .flatMap(this.authorizedClientManager::authorize)
            );
    // @formatter:on
}
```